# SharedPreferences not to overwrite data

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to write a list with same values two times in the preferences and when I read it back I only get 1 result.
Here is my SharedPreferences Code :

```
public void storeDeviceDetails(final ArrayList<String> deviceDetails) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("devicePrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        set.addAll(deviceDetails);
        editor.putStringSet("deviceDetails", set);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> retrieveDeviceDetails() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("devicePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ArrayList<String> details = null;

        Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("deviceDetails", null);

        if (set != null) {
            details = new ArrayList<>(set);
        }

        return details;
    }
```

I am writing it to List in 2 consecutive lines as -

```
MyPrefClass.storeDeviceDetails(myList);
MyPrefClass.storeDeviceDetails(myList);
```

And now in next line I do `MyPrefClass.retrieveDeviceDetails();` I only get it as - `[hero2lte, 7.0, hero2ltexx, SM-G935F, samsung]`

Comment: Better provide a real [mcve] for us; instead of putting down parts of your code.

Comment: you are passing a list to a set and a set does not hold duplicate values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i store two or more values with same key using SharedPreferences in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623098/can-i-store-two-or-more-values-with-same-key-using-sharedpreferences-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

You're making a new set, so it's overwriting the old one completely.

Try getting the set that's already in SharedPreferences if it exists, and only make a new one if it doesn't. Something like this:

```
Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("deviceDetails", null);

if (set == null) {
    set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you're adding the same elements twice. Even if you were to fix it, a `Set` guarantees uniqueness, so they'd only be added once anyway.

Comment: Ok actually I am trying to save array list in shared prefs. How can i do this ?

Comment: @Cruncher SharedPreferences doesn't store lists.  If he needs that, he needs to use another storage mechanism.  If set is sufficient for him, then your answer works.

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh okay. Storing as a json array is probably the best thing then

Comment: Thank you all. I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences instead of set and it worked :)