# How can I store a HashMap <Integer, String> in android using shared preferences?

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have created a HashMap in the following way:

`HashMap<Integer, String> buttons = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`

I need this to remain in this format, however every answer to this solution I have seen only works for `HashMap<String, String>`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a hash map into Shared Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944601/saving-a-hash-map-into-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hey I found a way in the end :)

I just changed the HashMap I had to format and then did the following to save the contents:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
for( Entry entry : backUpCurency_values.entrySet() ) 
editor.putString( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
editor.commit();
```

and the following to retrieve the HashpMap:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
for( Entry entry : prefs.getAll().entrySet() )
   backUpCurency_values.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString() );
```

Comment: Very elegant! You could also use `editor.putStringSet(...)` and `prefs.getStringSet(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for any `HashMap` in `SharedPreferences`. You can treat a whole `SharedPreferences` as being a bit like a `HashMap`, but it is not a `HashMap`, and you cannot store a `HashMap` in an individual preference.

You are welcome to convert your `HashMap` into a `String` that could be stored in a `SharedPreferences` value, such as by converting it into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Converting it to JSON (as CommonsWare pointed out) is an option. Alternatively, the way I did it (since I'm not familiar with JSON) is to serialize it with Apache's ObjectSerializer class (found here: [ObjectSerializer.java](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java)).

Simply call the serialize method when you want to store it and deserialize when you want to turn it back into a Map.