# Retrieve hashmap data SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I used `HashMap` to store data which I received using API. After that, I used SharedPreferences to store the received HashMap data. Storing part is done. I can see the number of records which I wanted to store using SharedPreferences.

Here is the code to save data:

```
if (result != null && result.length() > 0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++)
    {
       JSONObject resultObj = result.getJSONObject(j);
       String label_id = resultObj.getString("label_id");
       String arabic = resultObj.getString("arabic");
       String english = resultObj.getString("english");
       String key = resultObj.getString("key");

       //Create a new model and set the received value
       LabelModel labelModel = new LabelModel();
       labelModel.setLabelId(label_id);
       labelModel.setArabic(arabic);
       labelModel.setEnglish(english);
       labelModel.setKey(key);

       int label = Integer.parseInt(label_id);
       //Put the value

       map.put(label, labelModel);
     }
}

//With the below line, I stored the hashMap data using SharedPreferences
Pref.setValue(mActivity, AppPrefrences.PREF_LABELS, map);
```

After the above steps, I followed this set of code to **set** and **get** the value from SharePreferences, which I stored in application using SharedPreferences. 
For that, I used this below code:

```
public static String PREF_LABELS ="labels";

 public static void setValue(@NonNull Context context, String key, Object obj) {
    Pref.openPref(context);
    Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref.sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, String.valueOf(obj));
    prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
    prefsPrivateEditor = null;
    Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
}

@Nullable
public static String getValue(@NonNull Context context, String key, Object obj) {
    Pref.openPref(context);
    String result = Pref.sharedPreferences.getString(key, String.valueOf(obj));
    Pref.sharedPreferences = null;
    return result;
}
```

Now, I am trying to retrieve the data which I stored in SharedPreferences. 
Here is the code I used to retrieve the data:

```
String labels = Pref.getValue(mActivity, AppPrefrences.PREF_LABELS, "");
```

When I debug the app, I get values in **Labels** below format. The same number of records I received.

The format goes like this:

```
{572=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@23a282e, 598=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@c954fcf, 590=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@2fe3d5c, 103=com.*****..........}
```

How can I get the each data from this format?

Comment: store resultObj.toString()  in shared preference as string than retrieve as string and parse is the best practice !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for `HashMap` in SharedPreferences. So, you can't save the HashMap by converting it to a string directly, but you can convert it to JSON string. You can use [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson) in this case. Something like this:

First, include the dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Saving from HashMap object to preference:

```
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(map);
prefsEditor.putString("YourHashMap", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Get HashMap object from preference:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("YourHashMap", "");
HashMap map = gson.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead convert the map to gson String and store it in preference like this

```
   //convert to string using gson
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String mapString = gson.toJson(map);

    //save this in the shared prefs
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString("yourkey", mapString).apply();

    //get from shared prefs in gson and convert to maps again
    String storedHashMapString = prefs.getString("yourkey",null);
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType();

      //Get the hashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(storedHashMapString, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `{572=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@23a282e, 598=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@c954fcf, 590=com.*****.landlord.model.LabelModel@2fe3d5c, 103=com.*****..........}` this because Object default `toString()` method use `hashcode`.

Storing complex object in **SharedPreference** is not recommended. SharedPreference don't support **HashMap** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844642/1292557).

For storing simple object you have to convert the object into **String** using `toString()` method. 
You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for converting object to String and that will be a easy solution.

You can also use `ObjectOutputStream` to write it to the internal memory [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944773/1292557)

Answer (score 1):

You should cast lables string into hashmap object This is one solution. If you want to make it more generic, you can us StringUtils library.

```
String value = "{first_name = mohit,last_name = mathur,gender = male}";
value = value.substring(1, value.length()-1);           //remove curly brackets
String[] keyValuePairs = value.split(",");              //split the string to creat key-value pairs
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();               

for(String pair : keyValuePairs)                        //iterate over the pairs
{
    String[] entry = pair.split("=");                   //split the pairs to get key and value 
    map.put(entry[0].trim(), entry[1].trim());          //add them to the hashmap and trim whitespaces
}
```

For example, you can switch

```
value = value.substring(1, value.length()-1);
```

to

```
value = StringUtils.substringBetween(value, "{", "}");
```

and after that

You should cast  value in LabelModel
like

```
LabelModel labels = map.get("598");
```

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference doesn't support store map object. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html. So your code just store data obj.toString, that why you see result in debug. If you want to store a map, you can store as json and use put string.