# How store/save HashMap<String, List<String>>

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, expandablelistview

I have an expanded list, that is being made from `HashMap<String, List<String>>` , I would like to know if there is some kind possibility to store that value to preferences or something, so user could edit expanded list entries. Any information, suggestions will be appreciated.

Currently I am creating list in program and it is not saved to any prefs:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding header data
            listDataHeader.add("Vegetables");
            listDataHeader.add("Fruits");
            listDataHeader.add("Drinks");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> vegetables = new ArrayList<String>();
            vegetables.add("Tomatoes");
            vegetables.add("Potatoes");
            vegetables.add("Cucumbers");
            vegetables.add("Pumpkins");
            vegetables.add("Peppers");
            vegetables.add("Onions");
            vegetables.add("Garlic");

            List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
            fruits.add("Strawberries");
            fruits.add("Blackcurrants");
            fruits.add("Redcurrant");
            fruits.add("Gooseberry");
            fruits.add("Kiwifruit");
            fruits.add("Grape");

            List<String> drinks = new ArrayList<String>();
            drinks.add("Vodka");
            drinks.add("Milk");
            drinks.add("Water");
            drinks.add("CocaCola");
            drinks.add("Sprite");

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), vegetables); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), fruits);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), drinks);
        }


        private String does(String child) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Confirmation.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", child);
            startActivity(intent);
            return null;
        }

}
```

LOG

```
09-29 17:21:42.039: E/dalvikvm(25076): Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method lt.whiteGroup.ultimateshoppinglist.MainActivity.prepareListData
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at lt.whiteGroup.ultimateshoppinglist.MainActivity.prepareListData(MainActivity.java:117)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at lt.whiteGroup.ultimateshoppinglist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-29 17:21:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(25076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pretty  complicated structure so in your case I prefer to use [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) library to serialize (convert)  `HashMap<String, List<String>>` to `String` and store as basic String to preferences.

As example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String str = gson.toJson(listDataChild);
```

After store `str` as String

To fetch it back, extract String from Preferences as single `String` and load your `Map` like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, List<String>>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = gson.fromJson(str, type);
```

By this way you can store any class and get it back on next load.

*As a side note*

I use this technique to store all application configuration to preferences as handler on each change. By this way if crash will happen, data configured by user will be saved.

But if you still want to store map, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944601/saving-a-hash-map-into-shared-preferences) in SO

Comment: Thank you very much, you suggested a sound solution :). I will try to adapt it and write to you ASAP.

Comment: By the way if you have time, could you please explain what Gson and Json is?

Comment: Json is language that used to convert/extract any variable from/to String. When Gson is package that able to convert straight all your class to String

Comment: Thank you, because I have `listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);`, I will have to use gson and json on both `listDataHeader``listDataChild`, or there is easier way?

Comment: By the way what do I need for Gson and Json, because my eclipse does not suggest me anything to import

Comment: The easy way to use Gson. with 2-3 rows you can convert your class to String

Comment: add `gson-1.7.1.jar` to your project

Comment: You mean, I can convert all my class i.e. `MainActivity` and have like saved instance of it? And then next time just to load it back?

Comment: actually Activity you can but you can't load it because you get on start new instance. We use it mostly for data Objects. You can google

Comment: Do I need to define gson class in manifest? I got force close saying `coud not find class`

Comment: I did so, and then I was able to import and compile. Error log updated above

Comment: go to project -> right click ->Properties -> Java build path -> Order and export Tab, select there checkbox with your jar, after clean project and run again