# How to invoke getApplicationContext() from jni?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm facing a problem that JNI needs to call a Context from Java. I'm expecting to use getApplicationContext() to create a jobject as a context from JNI.
Then I will be using this jobject to call several other methods such as getPackageManger.

Please take note that I won't pass a Context object to JNI.
Give me some solutions that can help my app done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7998222/1739882

Comment: create newObject from Application class using jni methods.